# Extract zip to server and upload the files to the node?

Tags: 7, media, files

I allow users to upload zip files I extract, and look into them to see if they contain a .jpg file. I use that file to create a new node. The differences between the .jpg and the .zip file uploaded are that the first came as an object, while I don't know how I can take the second as an object.

I'm using the [PclZip](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/user-guide/55/) library.

This is part of the code I use when the uploaded file is a JPEG.

```
$file = $form_state['values']['file'];

$original_filename = $file->filename;
$original = file_unmanaged_copy($file->uri, 'public://work', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
file_unmanaged_delete($file->uri);
list($file, $tfile) = some_fileprep($original_filename);
```

This is the code I use when the file is a .zip file.

```
include $pclzip_lib.'pclzip.lib.php';
$zip = new PclZip($file->uri);


for ($i=0; $i<$total_files; $i++) {
    $file_name = $list[$i]['filename'];
    list($f_name,$xt) = explode('.', $file_name);
    $xt=strtolower($xt);

    $regex = '/\.(' . preg_replace('/ +/', '|', preg_quote('png gif jpg jpeg tif tiff html')) . ')$/i';
    if (preg_match($regex, $xt) and ($list[$i]['size'] < 10000000)) {
        $error[] = "File with conflict: ".$file_name;
        if((($xt == 'png') or ($xt == 'gif') or ($xt == 'jpg') or ($xt == 'jpeg') or ($xt == 'tif') or ($xt == 'tiff')) and ($f_name == 'preview')){
            $file->filename = $f_name.".".$xt;
            $file->uri = $f_name.".".$xt;
            echo "Yes: ".$f_name.".".$xt;
            $preview = true;
        }
    }

    if(is_null($error))
    {
            $to_extract = $GLOBALS['_SERVER']['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . drupal_get_path('module', 'some') . '/testing/';
            $ar = $zip->extract(PCLZIP_OPT_PATH, $to_extract);
            $file->filename = $ar->filename;
            $file->uri = $ar->filename;

        }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem and/or question here?

Comment: when you upload a jpg or a file, drupal take it as an object, so, I'm uploading a zip and I need to extract it, I put the files into the server and need to take one of this files like if it was uploaded by normal mode (as an object), how can I do that? (I'm from Argentina and my english isn't good, sry about the grammar)

Comment: You should show `some_fileprep()`'s code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you successfully unzip a file you have the code:

> ```
> if(is_null($error))
> {
>         $to_extract = $GLOBALS['_SERVER']['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . drupal_get_path('module', 'some') . '/testing/';
>         $ar = $zip->extract(PCLZIP_OPT_PATH, $to_extract);
>         $file->filename = $ar->filename;
>         $file->uri = $ar->filename;
> }
> ```

Once you've extracted the zip you have a $file object ... just save it using the drupal API such as:

`$original = file_unmanaged_copy($file->uri, 'public://work', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);`

Comment: Hi tenken, thanks for the answer, but when I make a var_dump($file->filename) or var_dump($file->uri) or var_dump($ar->filename) I get nulls, but the file was extracted, how can take it as an object?

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use [file_unmanaged_save_data()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_unmanaged_save_data/7), as in the following code, where `$data` is the content of the .jpeg file contained the .zip file.

```
file_unmanaged_save_data($data, 'public://work', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

As side note, Drupal includes the [ArchiverZip](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.archiver.inc/class/ArchiverZip/7) class, which should probably be used instead of the `PclZip` class.
You don't normally deal with the class directly, but you use code similar to the following one, used by [update_manager_archive_extract()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!update!update.manager.inc/function/update_manager_archive_extract/7).

```
  $archiver = archiver_get_archiver($file);
  if (!$archiver) {
    throw new Exception(t('Cannot extract %file, not a valid archive.', array('%file' => $file)));
  }

  // Remove the directory if it exists, otherwise it might contain a mixture of
  // old files mixed with the new files (e.g. in cases where files were removed
  // from a later release).
  $files = $archiver->listContents();

  // Unfortunately, we can only use the directory name to determine the project
  // name. Some archivers list the first file as the directory (i.e., MODULE/)
  // and others list an actual file (i.e., MODULE/README.TXT).
  $project = strtok($files[0], '/\\');

  $extract_location = $directory . '/' . $project;
  if (file_exists($extract_location)) {
    file_unmanaged_delete_recursive($extract_location);
  }

  $archiver->extract($directory);
```

[archiver_get_archiver()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/archiver_get_archiver/7) uses [drupal_realpath()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/drupal_realpath/7); this means it is able to get the realpath of a file when its filename is using stream wrappers, such as public://archive.zip.

Comment: Hi kiamlaluno, Thanks for the answer, When I started with this, the first thing i tried to use was the ArchiverZip class, but unfortunately, I can't understand it at all, because when I read the documentation, this says something about edit the php.ini and I have no access to that file (Production server), so, the ArchiverZip was discarded immediately, but, I'll to make a new read about it, thanks.

Comment: I don't have access to the php.ini file in my web server, but `update_manager_archive_extract()` works fine; in fact, I am updating the modules using the update manager, and it works. As far as I know, the Zip extension is normally enabled, in PHP 5.

Comment: Hello Again kiamlaluno, 
I'm trying to use ArchverZip as you says, but I'm getting an exception, this is the code (for now):

`$zip = new ArchiverZip($file->uri);`

Where $file->uri is the URI of the zipped file, and this is the exception I'm getting

`Exception: Cannot open <em class="placeholder">temporary://ahi_va_preview.zip</em> in ArchiverZip->__construct() (line 91 of /var/www/html/modules/system/system.archiver.inc).`

Some ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check the process running PHP has the right file permissions on the directory used as directory for temporary files.