# Extract compressed files

Tags: files

How to extract zip files after the upload successfully, I'm using **File Field Paths** to upload files.

Comment: You can extract them first and then upload.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's contain folders and files.

Comment: are u using PuTTy?

Comment: Nop, I need to make it auto extract after upload, I use IIS7

Comment: I find this public function [**ArchiverZip::extract**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.archiver.inc/function/ArchiverZip%3A%3Aextract/7), but I don't know how to use it, I'm new in drupal! :(

Comment: What do you want to do with the extracted files? Do they need to all then be managed by Drupal as if you uploaded them separately? Do you need to preserve file structure? The more information you can give the better chance of getting a useful answer.

Comment: Not a complete example but there is an example at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/35748/10729